# Alinhar ítens do form com CSS

Tags: php, css, html5, bootstrap

Olá, eu gostaria de uma ajuda para alinhar os ítens do seguinte form. Eu gostaria que os labels dos selects ficassem acima dos mesmos à exemplo dos labels dos inputs. Adicionalmente gostaria que os selects, os imputs e os button ficassem alinhados no bottom do da div. Agradeço à quem puder me ajudar pois apesar de ter tentado pesquisar não consegui fazer.

[image: Imagem do form como está atualmente]

```
<form class="form-inline" method="POST" action="../views/menu.php?pag=finalizados">

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div id="aposta_filtro">

                        <div class="form-group form-group-jogo">
                            <label for="regional_aposta">Regional</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="regional_aposta" name="ra">
                                <?php preenche_reg_combo(); ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-group-jogo">
                            <label for="regional_aposta">Cambista</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="regional_aposta" name="ra">
                                <?php preenche_cambista_combo(); ?>
                            </select>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group form-group-jogo">
                            <label for="filtroInicial">Data Inicial</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control js_date" 
                                   id="filtroInicial"
                                   required="true"
                                   name="data_inicial" 
                                   value="
                                   <?php 
                                        if(isset($di))
                                        {
                                            echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($di));
                                        }
                                        else
                                   ?>"
                            >
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group form-group-jogo">
                            <label for="filtroFinal">Data Final</label>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control js_date" 
                                   id="filtroFinal" 
                                   required="true"
                                   name="data_final" 
                                   value="
                                   <?php 
                                        if(isset($df))
                                        {
                                            echo date("d/m/Y", strtotime($df));
                                        }
                                   ?>"
                            >
                        </div>
                        <button id="submitDataFiltro" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" 
                                title="Filtrar">
                            Filtrar <span class="fa fa-filter"></span>
                        </button>
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Para colocar a legenda acima dos botões:** você deve **REMOVER** a classe '`class="form-inline"`', e sem seguida montar um `grid` (adicionando `<div class="row"> .... </row>`) e definindo a largura de cada campo (`.col-??-??`).

Leia mais em:

- [Bootstrap forms](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms).
- [Boostrap grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)

**Para colocar os campos alinhados à BASE:** uma forma é utilizar o CSS:

```
.form-group{
  float: none;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}
```

Veja no [**JsFiddle um exemplo funcionando**](https://jsfiddle.net/4bfj9fvw/) (redimensione a largura da visualização)

Comment: Precisamente! Obrigado pela ajuda, amigo. Vou ler mais assim afim de melhorar minhas habilidades com CSS.